# Without a second join to a first join, how do I add values from a filter list of first join, to the result of the first join, to added row values?

Tags: mysql, join, set, union

**Introduction**

The title as as generic as possible to extend to a broad audience, and the question is as specific to my problem as possible identical to my issue as possible so I can get maximum audience coverage but get a specific solution.

**Summary**

I have missing records that should display in my desired query but are not showing up, because they are not present in one table of a join.  I want to accomplish addition of the missing records without using a second join.  My question follows, along with a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, with a desired result.  See below for details.

**Question**

How do I select two columns from a result of a join query, then use a where clause to display those results from the join also displaying the non matching rows

> from  the set

of my in clause that have a column

> not in the set

in the most time efficient manner as possible?

**What I want?** 10 rows

```
columna columnb     columnc

val01   (null)      (null)
val02   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val03   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val04   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val05   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val06   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val07   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val08   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val09   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val10   2020-01-01  2020-01-01

num rows returned: 10
```

**What I get?**  9 rows - one less row from 10 row expectation

```
columna columnb     columnc
val02   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val03   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val04   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val05   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val06   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val07   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val08   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val09   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
val10   2020-01-01  2020-01-01

num rows returned: 9
```

**What I have tried?**

I have tried union (not shown below, but if desired can be added to question details), leading to much more records than necessary. But on analysis, the primary issue lies in the misuse of my filter on join, which does not include the missing record on columnA.

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tableb` (
  `col1` char NOT NULL,
  `columna` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `columnb` date,
  `columnc` date
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `tableb` (`col1`, `columna`, `columnb`, `columnc`) VALUES
  ('a', 'val01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'),
  ('b', 'val02', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'),
  ('c', 'val03', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'),
  ('d', 'val04', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'),
  ('e', 'val05', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'),
  ('f', 'val06', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'),
  ('g', 'val07', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'),
  ('h', 'val08', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'),
  ('i', 'val09', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'),
  ('j', 'val10', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01');
  
  
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tablea` (
  `col1` char(2) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `tablea` (`col1`) VALUES
  ('b'),
  ('c'),
  ('d'),
  ('e'),
  ('f'),
  ('g'),
  ('h'),
  ('i'),
  ('j');
```

**Expected Result Query:**

```
select desired.columna, desired.columnb, desired.columnc from 
        (select * from (select 'val01' as columna, null as columnb, null as columnc) `t1` union
         select * from (select 'val02' as columna, '2020-01-01' as columnb, '2020-01-01' as columnc) `t2` union
         select * from (select 'val03' as columna, '2020-01-01' as columnb, '2020-01-01' as columnc) `t3` union
         select * from (select 'val04' as columna, '2020-01-01' as columnb, '2020-01-01' as columnc) `t4` union
         select * from (select 'val05' as columna, '2020-01-01' as columnb, '2020-01-01' as columnc) `t5` union
         select * from (select 'val06' as columna, '2020-01-01' as columnb, '2020-01-01' as columnc) `t6` union
         select * from (select 'val07' as columna, '2020-01-01' as columnb, '2020-01-01' as columnc) `t7` union
         select * from (select 'val08' as columna, '2020-01-01' as columnb, '2020-01-01' as columnc) `t8` union
         select * from (select 'val09' as columna, '2020-01-01' as columnb, '2020-01-01' as columnc) `t9` union
         select * from (select 'val10' as columna, '2020-01-01' as columnb, '2020-01-01' as columnc) `t10`) desired;
```

**Actual Query:**

```
 #Actual Result

/*Goal: Basically, alongside the join results, I want to 
                                               also display the rows from the set of the NOT IN clause based upon 
                                               the column, that are not in the result set of the 
                                               join, which would show columnb, columnc as null*/
SELECT   columna, 
         columnb, 
         columnc 
FROM     tablea a, tableb b   # inner join
WHERE    a.col1 = b.col1      # on a.col1 = b.col1  
AND      b.columna  IN ('val01', 'val02', 'val03', 'val04', 'val05', 'val06', 'val07', 'val08', 'val09', 'val10')   
                                             /* 
                                               Presently: Using IN returns 9 rows in this query
                                             */
UNION
SELECT   columna, 
         columnb, 
         columnc 
FROM     tablea a, tableb b   # inner join
WHERE    a.col1 = b.col1      # on a.col1 = b.col1
AND      b.columna NOT IN ('val01', 'val02', 'val03', 'val04', 'val05', 'val06', 'val07', 'val08', 'val09', 'val10')   
                                             /* 
                                               Presently: Using NOT IN returns 0 rows in this query because my 
                                               join is returning result of that join 
                                               BUT not adding the values not present in the join from the "not in" 
                                               set to the set of results.
                                             */
GROUP BY b.columna ,find_in_set("b.columna", "val01, val02, val03, val04, val05, val06, val07, val08, val09, val10")    # find_in_set is here to adhere to original order of a.col1
```

SQL Fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c98a7/28

Comment: Here's how: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry, Thank you for the helpful reminder, a MCRE is necessary it this case to provide more clarity into the problem at hand and to avoid any syntax errors, or unnecessary effort on the part of the answerer.

Comment: Please see edited sql fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c98a7/17

Comment: The fiddle is a good start, but it would help if you showed the resultset you are hoping for, we can see the tables you are starting with but it is difficult to understand the expected result from the query.  With the expected result it will be easier to understand what the query needs to do.

Comment: I will revise fiddle to show an expected outcome

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c98a7/28

Comment: Initiating a bounty, since answers are not present and comments provided are helpful, but do not help answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `LEFT JOIN` and condition in `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT tb.columnA, 
     IF(ta.col1 IS NULL, NULL, tb.columnb) AS columnb, 
     IF(ta.col1 IS NULL, NULL, tb.columnc) AS columnc
FROM tableb tb
LEFT JOIN tablea ta
  ON tb.col1 = ta.col1;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=356ef58da60f62a0fb50ba641403f5d3)**

Using `CASE` expression(more generic):

```
SELECT tb.columnA, 
     CASE WHEN ta.col1 IS NOT NULL THEN tb.columnb END AS columnb, 
     CASE WHEN ta.col1 IS NOT NULL THEN tb.columnc END AS columnc
FROM tableb tb
LEFT JOIN tablea ta
  ON tb.col1 = ta.col1
```

---

If column we are joining is unique then double `LEFT JOIN` could be used:

```
SELECT tb.columnA, 
       tb2.columnb, 
       tb2.columnc
FROM tableb tb
LEFT JOIN tablea ta
  ON tb.col1 = ta.col1
LEFT JOIN tableb tb2
  ON ta.col1 = tb2.col1;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b3f4125f1e471c96bded5e49759055a)**

---

EDIT:

> can you help answer if there is any other way to accomplish this other than the join

Using correlated subquery:

```
SELECT tb.columnA, 
     CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablea ta WHERE tb.col1 = ta.col1)
          THEN tb.columnb 
     END AS columnb, 
     CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablea ta WHERE tb.col1 = ta.col1)
         THEN tb.columnc 
     END AS columnc
FROM tableb tb
```

**[db<>fiddle demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39d735d22989473736fec783512c2b60)**

And `LATERAL JOIN` but no real advantages over regular `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT tb.columnA, 
     CASE WHEN s.c IS NOT NULL THEN tb.columnb END AS columnb, 
     CASE WHEN s.c IS NOT NULL THEN tb.columnc END AS columnc
FROM tableb tb
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT 1 c FROM tablea ta WHERE tb.col1 = ta.col1 LIMIT 1) s ON TRUE
```

---

And using mutually exclusive `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT tb.columnA, 
       tb.columnB,
       tb.columnC
FROM tableb tb
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablea ta WHERE ta.col1 = tb.col1)
UNION ALL
SELECT tb.columnA, 
       NULL AS columnB,
       NULL AS columnC
FROM tableb tb
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablea ta WHERE ta.col1 = tb.col1)
```

**[db<>fiddle demo4](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6ecd7783a2567635790753a90a7805b2)**

Comment: Before I award the bounty.  can you help answer if there is any other way to accomplish this other than the join.

Comment: @VaheJabagchourian Technically speaking you could use correlated subquery(LATERAL is kind of join anyway) but it won't be any faster, easier to read. Let me prepare demo

Comment: Please provide a complete (syntactical based) example for me and a reader of the question to see, in order to fully answer the question. For this, amount of bounty, would you be willing to generalize the answer if desired, it is not a mandate, just a request...

Comment: Since I have an arbitrary number of missing records, how should I modify the correlated subquery, (a term I did not know until now, to describe this type of subquery), in order to accomplish the desired outcome for an arbitrary list of missing records, if possible?  And thank you for you prompt response.

Comment: @VaheJabagchourian The challenge here is you need to provide CASE expression for each column you want to handle that way. I have provided final approach that combines `UNION ALL` and `EXISTS`

Comment: Lukasz, your efforts and comprehensive answer are very much appreciated. Thank you. I have a 2 hour wait window to award bounty.